# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown on Hover if not mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make bootstrap dropdown list from navbar to appear on hover but stop the hover effect on collapsed (mobile). This is what I have in mind, but when I add the if statement the whole effect doesnt work: 
HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand vaos" href="../index.html">VAOS</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a class="trans" href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">What is VAOS <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="options.html">VAOS & Other Options</a></li>
              <li><a href="candidate.html">Am I a Candidate</a></li>
              <li><a href="surgeon.html">Find a Surgeon</a></li>
              <li><div class="ArrowUp1"></div></li>
            </ul>
         </li>

          <li><a href="experience.html">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Resources <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="clinical-support.html">Clinical Support</a></li>
              <li><a href="videos.html">Procedural Videos</a></li>
              <li><a href="resources.html">Other Links & Resources</a></li>
              <li><div class="ArrowUp2"></div></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav .open ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover {
    background: #e7e7e7;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #969696;
    background: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav .hovernav:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
'use strict';

$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  if(window.width > 767) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  }   
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work with or without the if statement, but one problem is that `window.width` is undefined. You probably want `window.innerWidth` instead.

Comment: I would consider detecting the pointer type with modernizr instead of usins the screen size for this kind of feature, because hover effects are not very handy on tablets too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it without any scripting language.
Just try this.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand vaos" href="../index.html">VAOS</a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a class="trans" href="../index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">What is VAOS <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="options.html">VAOS & Other Options</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="candidate.html">Am I a Candidate</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="surgeon.html">Find a Surgeon</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="ArrowUp1"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="experience.html">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Resources <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="clinical-support.html">Clinical Support</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="videos.html">Procedural Videos</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="resources.html">Other Links & Resources</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="ArrowUp2"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

It is smooth and handy. +1 if it helps.

Comment: How to make a dropdown button clickable on desktops ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the css hover for the item with class dropdown and set the dropdown-menu class to diplay block

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
            display:block;
        }
    }
```